# Spring Cloud Feign + Sleuth + Zipkin - original request is required

Tags: spring, zipkin, feign

I have multiservices application which is using Spring Cloud OpenFeign. Now I have to use zipkin with that app. I remember that when i had app without Feign I just added Sleuth and Zipkin starters dependencies and run zipkin server on port 9411. After that Zipkin worked well.. But now, when i try same in my app with Feign i get error 500 **"original request is required"**. I guess that Feign has some problems with headers when Sleuth add traces informations. Can you help me fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's hard to tell without more information. But it can be related to **incompatible libraries**. Can you post your dependencies?

In case you are using **older version** of okhttpclient with **latest** spring cloud:greenwich it can cause this issue.

I'm using **Greenwich.RELEASE** with **okhttpclient:10.2.0** which works without problems

Comment: +1 Thanks. I had the above error message in Feign using two different "Feign Clients" in my project which based on different Feign versions. At the end the feign-core 10.x had this issue with feign-okhttp 9.x. which was easy to detect using mvn dependency:tree once I knew what to look for. The spring-cloud-dependencies Greenwich.RELEASE pulled all versions up so they ended up to be compatible.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below dependency Management for spring-boot to download the suitable versions for cloud version

```
    <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I am using Java 10, cloud.version is **Finchley.SR2** and sprinb-boot:2.2.0 and spring-cloud-starter-openfeign :2.1.2.RELEASE. and this combination worked for me to fix the issue.

Acctual problem was 10.x.x feign-core  was not working only  and io.github.openfeign:feign-core:jar:9.7.0:compile was working.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this problem using java 11, springboot 2.3.0.RELEASE, and spring-cloud version Greenwich.RELEASE. Adding the following dependences saved me:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
        <artifactId>feign-okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
        <artifactId>feign-core</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Hope this helps someone.